# Current password field cannot be empty in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, upgrade

I have upgraded my Magento application form v1.7 to v1.9. Its running and I can login form admin. 
But when I am trying to add/edit user from System->permssions->user then It returns an error saying **Current password field cannot be empty.**  See the attached screen.[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Find the your template path and paste the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

just after `<form>` tag, [See how to enable the admin path hints.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento)

Comment: Hi, my path in is app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\form.phtml. But I added the above code to file after tags  and clear cached but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share the file code

Comment: <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 
 * DISCLAIMER


 */
?>
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
<div class="entry-edit">
    <?php echo $this->getFormHtml();?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_after');?>

Comment: No this is not right file

Comment: Your code should look like : <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/saverole') ?>" method="post" id="role_edit_form">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
</form>

Comment: Well, I think it generating html form tag and its fields from app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Permissions\User\Edit\Tab\Main.php

Comment: Also, when I look into source code, the form key is there.
<form id="edit_form" method="post" action="http://v9.magento.local/index.php/admin/permissions_user/save/key/5da0decb3c5841d4fe436f27aaec9a37/">
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="l3pTpwmovpiq2uj5" name="form_key">
</div>

Comment: If form key is present then it might be cookies problem try it in another browser

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9 the `edit user` form should include a `Current Admin Password` field. See mine: (1.9.2.4)

[image]

I had the same problem until I removed a tacky extension, in my case it was `Demac_AdminPermissions`

I suggest you go in `System/Advanced/Advanced` and turn off any third party extensions you have one by one and see if any of them made this field go missing. When the field is back, the module you turned off last is the culprit, you can turn the others back on.